# How did the atomic number and atomic mass of elements discovered?

Tags: atoms, elements, atomic-structure

Elements are small for our naked eyes.so,how did the discovery of its atomic number and mass number took place?

Comment: http://scienceline.ucsb.edu/getkey.php?key=408